# Why is spaCyText Processing So Slow?

Tags: performance, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am currently trying to process some text for my project, and I converted my NLTK function to a spaCy  one, hoping I can use some of spaCy advantages. After reading the docs, I added the list of texts to nlp Spacy Pipeline, as I understood that this is when the pipeline can really do its job well. I also added some extra options that should not slow the function down. The final function

The only extra feature that this has from the original NLTK function that had the same functionality is that I now also remove Personal Nouns / Names from the text. Everything else, like punctuation removal, stopwords removal, and lemmatization, is the same, just implemented in spaCy instead of NLTK.

```
nlp = spacy.load('ru_core_news_md', disable=['tok2vec, parser, morphologizer, attribute_ruler']) 

    
def preprocess(texts, remove_names=False, tokenize_text=False):
  clean_texts = []
  # remove unnecessary components of model to reduce the loading time and processing time
  for document in nlp.pipe(texts, disable=['tok2vec, parser, morphologizer, attribute_ruler'], n_process=1, batch_size=256): # pass texts to the model
    if remove_names == True:
      for token in document:
        text = [
          token.lemma_ for token in document
          if not token.is_punct # remove punctuation
          and not token.is_stop # remove stopwords
          and not token.like_num # remove numbers
          and token.is_alpha # keep letters only
          and token.ent_type_ not in ['PER'] # this is where I remove personal names
        ]
    else:
      for token in document: # everything same as above, but names are keptt
        text = [
          token.lemma_ for token in document
          if not token.is_punct
          and not token.is_stop
          and not token.like_num
          and token.is_alpha
        ]
    if tokenize_text == True:
      clean_texts.append(text)
    else:
      clean_texts.append(' '.join(text))
  return clean_texts
```

And this is how I run the function (I remove names, but do not tokenize the text).

```
texts_preprocessed = [preprocess (text, True, False) for text in full_text_list]
```

I have aroudn 23000 documents of text in my list. For half the size of this, NLTK took about 15 minutes. For this sample, spaCy has been running for more than an hour now.

Did I misunderstand how spaCy nlp pipe works? Could token.ent_type_ not in ['PER'] be causing it to be this slow? Or am I wrong somewhere else in my function. I am not sure if I should be worried about this processing.